# Upload external changes not working with GRUNT

Tags: macos, gruntjs, phpstorm, webstorm

I started using gruntjs today. Created all the required files etc.
Here is my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    concat: {
      options: {
        separator: "\n"
      },
      dist: {
        src: ['js/lib/*.js','js/main.js'],
        dest: 'js/script.js'
      }
    },
    sass: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'compressed'
        },
        files: {                                    // Dictionary of files
          'css/style.css': 'css/style.scss'         // 'destination': 'source'
        }
      }
    },
    uglify: {
      options: {
        sourceMap : true,
        mangle : false
      },
      my_target: {
        files: {
          'js/script.min.js': ['js/script.js']
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      css: {
        files: ['css/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['sass']
      },
      scripts: {
        files: ['js/lib/*.js','js/youtube.js','js/main.js'],
        tasks: ['concat', 'uglify']
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

};
```

and it works fine. But there is one little thing in my PHPstorm (running under osx):
GruntJS really makes the changes but they are not uploaded to the server I'm mapped to. I have the Automatic Upload and 'Upload External Changes' checked but still, nothing happens.

Could you somehow help me?
Thanks in advance!

P.s While using the PHPStorm file watchers (scss watcher), the 'Upload External Changes' was working and the files were uploading to server, but after switching to GruntJS the problem occurred.

Comment: do you run Grunt from within PHPStorm?

Comment: Yes I do. As I already mentioned, it works fine and makes changes to files but:
a) PHPStorm probably caches the files and the created files are not shown/seen until I refresh the directory.
b) Those files are not uploaded to webserver I'm mapped to

Comment: Check if your folder is not excluded from upload. https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/excluding-files-and-folders-from-upload-download.html

Comment: No mate, of course it's not excluded from upload :)

Comment: Do you use grunt with PHPStorm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using older (v8) version of PHPStorm.

In PHPStorm 10 Problem is solved !!!

Answer (score 0):

BTW, File > Synchronize solves the problem, as it reloads the files and then the 'Upload external changes' works, but that's not a very good solution as it's not automatic.

Also, switching the window probably makes PHPStorm synchronize files and this also helps.

Anyway, I'm in search of better solution..